# convert p to br on tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, inline-editing

Please help. I use tinyMCE as inline editor. So I need that when user in edit mode press enter then will be `<br />` not `<p>`. I read manual and FAQ and try

```
tinyMCE.init({
            'height' : '100%',
            'widht':'100%',
            'content_css' : styles + ',/sdtc-new/nc/interface/common/css/mce-editor.css',
            'mode' : "specific_textareas",
            'editor_selector' : prefix + o.id,
            'theme':'advanced',
        theme_advanced_buttons1: o.buttons.join(','),
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        **theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '' // Needed for 3.x**
        });
```

But it's not work . Actually some time it's work like when I delete all conetent in edit area and type new text. But i need that it works all time. Please help. Version of tinyMCE 3.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set

```
tinyMCE.init({
   forced_root_block : false,
   force_br_newlines : true,
   force_p_newlines : false
   ...
});
```

[Here is a helpfull section](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_produce_P_elements_on_enter.2Freturn_instead_of_BR_elements.3F) of the tinymce FAQ.

Comment: Are you mean that I use it in not correct order? Because I use this directives but in other order.

Comment: the order does not matter, but '' does not equal false !

Comment: console.log('' == false); //true

Comment: I try in FireFox 6.1 and TinyMCE 3.4.4

Comment: yes you right I saw at the code of tinyMCE and this settings really correct work only for IE but Shift+Enter work correctly in FF and IE and Google Chrome. Of course I can rebind keypress event but i think this is stuppid

Comment: you could do it using an own plugin, catching the onKeyDown event and execute what the shift+enter would do, + stopping further propagation to get no ps

Comment: stop propagation not correctly work in all browsers. stop bubuling work normal bu stop propagation very bad.

Comment: you can use this code to stop propagation in all cases if evt is your event:   evt.stopPropagation();evt.preventDefault();return false;